# How to get the height of a label

Tags: xamarin.forms

I made a grid with a frame and a label in it. But the height of the grid is too big.
I do not know how many words will be in the label.

So is there any way to get the height of the frame or the label?

and the grid always can not be adaptive to fit the frame.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6.6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Image Source="lf.png" />
    </StackLayout>
    <RelativeLayout Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#f0f8fa" x:Name="box1" Padding="9,9,20,9"
               HasShadow="false">
            <Label Text="慢性咽炎怎么办？" TextColor="#111111" FontSize="16" />
        </Frame>
        <Image Source="chat_left.png" WidthRequest="6" 
               HeightRequest="7.5" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
               Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=box1,Property=X,Factor=0,Constant=-6}" 
               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
               Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=box1,Property=Height,
               Factor=0.5,Constant=0}" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please provide a code of your xaml.

Comment: Hi @Денис Чорный glad to see you again。I added the code。

Comment: Hi, check the Lucas Zhang's answer.

Comment: Lucas Zhang's answer is not work

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot showing your layout and what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to let grid fit the size of label,you only need to set the height of **Row** or width of **Column** as **Auto**

```xml
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Label x:Name="label1" BackgroundColor="Red" Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" Grid.Row="0"  SizeChanged="Label1_SizeChanged"/>

   <Label x:Name="label2" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" Grid.Row="1" SizeChanged="Label2_SizeChanged" />
</Grid>
```

And if you do want to get the height of label ,you can get it in the method **SizeChanged**

> in code behind

```cs
private void Label1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)sender;

    DisplayAlert("Title", "the height of label1 is " + label.Height, "cancel");
}

private void Label2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)sender;

    DisplayAlert("Title", "the height of label2 is " + label.Height, "cancel");
}
```

Comment: It is not work.I have to specify the height of the grid.

Comment: Can you provide an image about what effect did you want.